# heroku push fails with the error "An error occurred while installing sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sqlite

When I do

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following message:

```
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3-ruby -v '1.2.5'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

I have libsqlite3-dev, libsqlite3-0, sqlite3 all installed and when i run:

```
gem install sqlite3-ruby -v '1.2.5'
```

as suggested in the error message, it successfully installs:

```
Successfully installed sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5...
Installing RDoc documentation for sqlite3-ruby-1.2.5...
```

I'm not sure what may be the problem.

My Gemfile is:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.1'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5',:require => 'sqlite3'
```

May I know what is the problem and how I could solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support sqlite3.

So you need to change your Gemfile to be:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

And run `bundle install` again

Comment: Remember to commit before pushing to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure you have to use a Postgres database with heroku

Answer (score 0):

You can't use SQLite on Heroku. You'll need to use postgres, as per this article: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/database

I suggest also installing postgres locally for testing and using it; if you are using OS X use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install it, otherwise try one of the binaries on the official postgres site.